# Multi dimensional dictionary?

Tags: java

I'm trying to find a simple/efficient way to store multiple values under each index for my application, for example:

```
1 = {54, "Some string", false, "Some other string"}
2 = {12, "Some string", true, "Some other string"}
3 = {18, "Some string", true, "Some other string"}
```

So that I can set this as a static variable which can then be accessed from various object instances via the single index value (the only variable within each object). Essentially, sort of like a "multi dimensional dictionary".

I have looked at 2D arrays, but they seem to be limited to single data types (Int, string, etc) and also looked at hash maps - which also seemed limited as if using more than two values, would require a list variable which again comes back the the single data type problem. Any advice on a simple solution for this please?

Comment: Create a new class?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Define a class for those entries, and use an array of objects. So the class might be something like:

```
class Thingy {
    private int someNumber;
    private String someString;
    private boolean someBool;
    private String someOtherString;

    public Thingy(int _someNumber, String _someString, boolean _someBool, String _someOtherString) {
        this.someNumber = _someNumber;
        this.someString = _someString;
        this.someBool = _someBool;
        this.someOtherString = _someOtherString;
    }

    public int getSomeNumber() {
        return this.someNumber;
    }
    // ...setter if appropriate...

    // ...add accessors for the others...
}
```

...and then you do:

```
Thingy[] thingies = new Thingy[] {
    new Thingy(54, "Some string", false, "Some other string"),
    new Thingy(12, "Some string", true, "Some other string"),
    new Thingy(18, "Some string", true, "Some other string")
};
```

Answer (score 0):

The backbone of Python heavily relies on dictionary data structures, many instances can be reflected, assigned and accessed through using the `__dict__` attribute. If you have a model that frequently has to access a dozen dictionaries or so, replicating something like the following in Python would reduce quite a lot of the unnecessary Java idiosyncrasies:

```python
class ExampleObject:
    spam = "example"
    title = "email title"
    content = "some content"

obj = ExampleObject()

print obj.spam # prints "example"

print obj.__dict__["spam"] # also prints "example"
```

Just throwing an alternative option out there for you.